# Deeply nested search through Document tree

Tags: c#

I have this code block, where I search for the value of `Ordnungsbegriff`. I have to search through a tree of my CurrentDocument.

How can I rewrite it to be more dynamic? I don't know at which level I will find my value.

```
string xy = "";        
try
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff))
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff))
                        {
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff))
                            {
                                xy = "Nach 6. Ebene, Suche abgebrochen.";
                            }
                            else
                                xy = CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff;
                        }
                        else
                            xy = CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff;
                    }
                    else
                        xy = CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff;
                }
                else
                    xy = CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff;
            }
            else
                xy = CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff;
        }
        else
            xy = CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff;
    }
    else
      xy = CurrentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff;

}
catch (Exception)
{
    xy = "Fehler in  Suche";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. What exactly do you mean by "I don't know at which level I find my value." Is this your code?

Comment: Yes, this is my code. I have CurrentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff, if this is null then i search at CurrentDocument.ParentDocument.Ordnungsbegriff and so on, until i find a value for Ordnungsbegriff

Answer (score 10):

I find [recursion complicated](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/85055/22816) You can use a while loop:

```
private string SearchDocument(Document doc)
{
    while (doc != null) 
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc.Ordnungsbegriff))
        {
            return doc.Ordnungsbegriff;
        }
        doc = doc.ParentDocument;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Edit: As a further point - it's better not to mix languages in your code: `Ordnungsbegriff` should be `Keyword` (according to Google).

Comment: A very nice alternative. I hadn't considered an iterative approach.

Answer (score 8):

[Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). You need some recursion friend.

Create a function that returns the value if it's found or calls itself on the next level if it's not found. This may not be a 100% working solution, because I don't have quite enough context for that, but it should give you a good start.

```
private string SearchDocument(Document doc)
{
    if (doc == null)
    {
        return "Nach 6. Ebene, Suche abgebrochen.";
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc.Ordnungsbegriff))
    {
        return SearchDocument(doc.ParentDocument);
    }

    return doc.Ordnungsbegriff
}
```

If you don't know much (or anything) about recursion, I recommend [this video from Computerphile](https://youtu.be/Mv9NEXX1VHc). It's a very good primer on the topic.

Comment: Have you ever read [the little schemer](http://kysmykseka.net/koti/wizardry/Programming/Lisp/Scheme/The%20Little%20Schemer%204th%20Ed.pdf)? It blew my mind then I forgot most of it but it's the closest I've ever come to being comfortable with recursion!

Comment: No, but I'm about to @RobH. =) It took me a while to get comfortable with recursion myself, but once you get it you *get it*. I really do recommend the video linked in my answer. It's a very good explination.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I really like RobH's solution. If you find that traversing the document hierarchy is a common operation in your code, consider introducing a method `AncestorsAndSelf()` to your `Document` class (alternatively, make it an extension method):

```
public IEnumerable<Document> AncestorsAndSelf()
{
    for (var document = this; document != null; document = document.ParentDocument)
    {
        yield return document;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to write the method in a more declarative way

```
private static string SearchDocument(Document document)
{
    return document.AncestorsAndSelf()
        .Select(d => d.Ordnungsbegriff)
        .FirstOrDefault(o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o));
}
```